# Convert Video to Image Sequence MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video

i am trying to convert a video to image sequences, and at mathworks i saw the code like this

Read and play back the movie file xylophone.mp4.

```
xyloObj = VideoReader('xylophone.mp4');

nFrames = xyloObj.NumberOfFrames;
vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;
vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;
```

Preallocate the movie structure.

```
mov(1:nFrames) = ...
    struct('cdata',zeros(vidHeight,vidWidth, 3,'uint8'),...
           'colormap',[]);
```

Read one frame at a time.

```
for k = 1 : nFrames
    mov(k).cdata = read(xyloObj,k);
end
```

while i am trying this code, it requires a very long time to compile it. Is there any way to read all frame without looping so i can make it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to take a long time regardless of what you do.  What you're doing is uncompressing each frame and placing the raw RGB frames into memory.  As such, the time is being spent in I/O and performing a decoding of the frames into RGB.   However, what may be faster for you in the long run is to batch read a bunch of frames with a single `read` call first and then they're available for use later on.

The `read` method allows you to specify a two element vector as the second input that tells MATLAB the range of frames you want to read.   For example, if you wanted to read the first 10 frames, do this:

```
video = read(xyloObj, [1 10]);
```

`video` is a 4-D array where the first dimension is the height of a frame, the second dimension is the width, the third dimension is the number of colour channels (usually 3) and the fourth dimension is the frame number.  Therefore, if you wanted to access the `i`th frame, you'd do:

```
frame = video(:,:,:,i);
```

Also, if you called `read` without the second parameter, this reads in all of the frames from the beginning to end.  As such, you can also just do this:

```
video = read(xyloObj);
```

In the `xylophone.mp4` file (on my computer), there are 141 frames and doing the above on my computer took about 13 seconds. My configuration is Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.3 running MATLAB R2013a with 16 GB of RAM on an Intel Core i7 2.3 GHz.  This makes sense from what we talked about before and now the frames are  available as a 4D matrix.

So perhaps one thing that could work is to use `read` and just read in all of the frames without looping.  If that's slow, then perhaps you can read in every 10 or 20 frames or so at one time, process the frames, then proceed to the next batch.... so something like this:

```
for idx = 1 : 20 : nFrames
    if idx + 20 > nFrames
        endIndex = nFrames;
    else
        endIndex = idx + 20;
    end
    video = read(xyloObj, [idx endIndex-1]);

    %// Continue processing
end
```

However, if you just use the `read` command by itself without any second inputs, if you can wait about 13 seconds or so then that's totally fine.  Besides which, if you really wanted to make use of the frames for later, you can always employ [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) and store the frames in a MAT file for ease of loading and use for later.

Comment: so how about if i process the video directly after i read the frame? is it make difference if i convert the video to the image sequence first?

Comment: @BrilianAringga - Not really no!  It's gonna take a long time no matter what you do.  The reason why it takes a long time is due to I/O and uncompressing the frames.  The reason why you would want to convert it to an image sequence first is that you only have to do the `read` call once.    Once you do that, then it's just a matter of slicing into the image sequence matrix to get the frames you need.  However, that's going to eat up a lot of memory, so you have to decide what's better and easier for you... either reading in a frame one frame at a time, or doing it all at once.

Comment: oooh i got it! so i can reduce the time process because i don't need to read the frame again right?

Comment: @BrilianAringga - Right you are!  Just call `read` once, and now the frames will be available after that point for you to use. :)  I've edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: i got the point now, aaw thank you so much master @rayryeng for your explain xD